# An app that can scan archive files and delete them

Tags: macos, archive

I'm looking for an app that have this features:

1. Scan all archive files inside a directory (say, Downloads folder)
2. Determine whether if I have already extracted the archive files or not (inside the directory)
3. If I have already extracted the archive files, then delete them (archive files). If I'm not extracted them yet, keep it inside the directory

Any recommendations?

Comment: What do you use to 'unzip'? Many apps will delete upon successful completion *edit* including Apple's own Archive Utility. Of the 3rd party freebies, [Stuffit Expander](http://my.smithmicro.com/stuffit-expander-mac.html) springs to mind as nicely configurable in that respect.

Answer (score 1):

To automate things like that, I use **[Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php)** (paid software, 29$).

> Hazel watches whatever folders you tell it to, automatically
>   organizing your files according to the rules you create. It features a
>   rule interface similar to that of Apple Mail so you should feel right
>   at home. Have Hazel move files around based on name, date, type, what
>   site/email address it came from (Safari and Mail only) and much more.
>   Automatically put your music in your Music folder, movies in Movies.
>   Keep your downloads off the desktop and put them where they are
>   supposed to be.